# jquery use this after this.parent.remove

Tags: jquery

here is my funcitons

```
$(document).on("click", ".size_remove", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent(".size_container").remove();
        $(this).parents(".size_container").parent('.size_editor')
               .find('.size_container').each( function (cloneIndex, clonedElement) {
            updateClonedSize(cloneIndex + 1, clonedElement);
        })
    });
```

because `$(this).parent(".size_container").remove()`,

cause

```
$(this).parents(".size_container").parent('.size_editor')
       .find('.size_container').each( function (cloneIndex, clonedElement) {
            updateClonedSize(cloneIndex + 1, clonedElement);
        });
```

not working. wondering is there anything i can do to solve this issue.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parent after finish cloning of elements like below:

```
$(document).on("click", ".size_remove", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents(".size_container").parent('.size_editor')
           .find('.size_container').each( function (cloneIndex, clonedElement) {
        updateClonedSize(cloneIndex + 1, clonedElement);
    });
    $(this).parent(".size_container").remove();
});
```

Because when you're removing parent and then again going to use parent again, then it's not getting the parent anymore and doesn't work.

Comment: thanks for reply, sorry i forget to mention that updateClonedSize function change all the id increment. so if i put the $(this).parent(".size_container").remove() , this parent wouldn't be remove.